# How do I include an animation cdn in react

Tags: reactjs

Can someone show me how I can include an animation cdn library in my react app., I mean how do I link it up. I tried linking the cdn in my root html(index.html) but, how do I link it up with the external components files am working with ? thanks

Comment: Can u please share what CDN u using ?

Comment: aos (animation library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Including the library

Including the css and javascript:

```
// ...
<head>
  // ...
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  // ...
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
</body>
// ...
```

## Initializing and using the library

```
function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.AOS.init({ // Initialization
      duration: 2000
    });
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      // Doing something with the library
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          backgroundColor: "blue"
        }}
        data-aos="fade-up">
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have another question above, probably you can assist too @Bas Van see Linden